# Как перенести функцию на readyRead QT

Tags: c++, qt, виджет, сигналы-слоты, обработка-сигналов

У меня есть код, который должен данные, выводимые bat файлом, отправлять в textLabel:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    QString program = "PyModuleInstaller.bat";

    QProcess *Process = new QProcess(this);
    Process->start(program);
    connect(Process, &QProcess::readAllStandardOutput, [&] {
        ui->label->setText(Process->readAllStandardOutput());
    });
}
```

И я хочу поменять в нём `readAllStandardOutput` на `readyReadStandardOutput()`. Если просто поменять - получаю ошибку: *too few arguments to function call, expected 1*. Я так понял нужно добавить сигнал в файле manwindow.h

Написал что-то(наверно даже не похоже на правильно):

```
private: signals:
    void Read();
```

Но я не понял, как правильно сделать такой сигнал, и как его присоединить к textLabel чтобы данные которые даёт выполняемый bat файл отправлялись в textLabel. Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: readyRead это только сигнал о том что байтики пришли. Он не читает. Нужно написать функцию которая прочтет буфер и добавит его к текту.

Comment: Я отвечал на такой вопрос недавно. Посмотрите тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1108753/16574

Comment: Правда там для питона, но суть та же

Comment: Там ещё есть кусок о том как выполнить несколько команд одна за другой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

сигнал readyReadStandardOutput испускается асинхронно, соответственно вам надо или накапливать где-то вывод и по завершении программы использовать, либо обрабатывать вывод по мере поступления.
Я заменил QLabel на QPlainTextEdit в который по мере вывода будут дописываться считываемые данные

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString program = "ping 127.0.0.1";
    QProcess *Process = new QProcess(this);
    Process->start(program);
    connect(Process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [=] {
        ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(Process->readAll());
    });
}
```

В заголовочный файл ничего добавлять не надо. Зачем? это же вами объявленный сигнал, который нигде не испускается.

Comment: вы соеденяете сигнал со слотом после старта