# Не могу получить вывод процесса в строку QT

Tags: c++, windows, qt, cmd, qwidget

Мне нужно считать вывод процесса QProcess в QString

```
QString program = "cmd", output;
    command = "cd /d ";
    command += QString::fromLocal8Bit(dir); //здесь хранится путь до папки, в которой должна исполняться команда
    command += " & pip list";
    qDebug() << command;
    arg << "/C" << command;
    QProcess *Process2 = new QProcess(this);
    Process2->start(program, arg);
    connect(Process2, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [&] {
       QString output(Process2->readAll());
    });
    qDebug() << output;
```

Я проверил - команда, которая хранится в command - работает, но в строке `qDebug() << output;` я получаю значение "". С кодировкой всё в порядке (команда сама по себе выводится и её можно скопировать и вставить в cmd - она сработает). Как мне получить в строку output вывод этого процесса?

Comment: а вас самого не смущает, что вы сначала стартуете процесс и только потом соединяете сигнал со слотом?

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch Делал как здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1123560/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bd%d0%b0-readyread-qt и сработало, но со строкой не получается

Comment: вы угараете там или как? мало того, что вы соединяете слоты после старта, так еще и выводите строку не в самой лямбде, а сразу после старта. По итогу у вас выведется пустая строка и только когда-то потом сработает лямбда

Comment: И вообще вы в лямбде создаете новую строку, которая затеняет уже объявленную...

Comment: Спасибо, попробую исправить)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. зачем в лямбде повторное объявление переменной? почитайте про область видимости переменных. У вас получается две переменных с одним именем.
2. В лямбде вы каждый раз переписываете значение, но данные будут поступать постепенно и у вас на руках останется только последняя порция.
3. Работа сигналов-слотов АСИНХРОННАЯ. И ожидать в последней строке готового вывода бесполезно - qDebug() << output; отработает еще до того как в output появятся данные

Вот

```
QString program = "ping 127.0.0.1";                          
QString* output = new QString(); // лямбда будет с доступом к переменным по значению, поэтому тут у нас будет указатель

QProcess *Process = new QProcess(this);                      
Process->start(program);                                     

connect(Process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [=] {   
        output->append(Process->readAll());   // НЕ ПЕРЕПИСЫВАЕМ а дописываем               
});                                                          
Process->waitForFinished(); // ЖДЕМ ЗАВЕРШЕНИЯ процесса
qDebug()<<output;
```

UPD: 
Еще как вариант, если все равно будет синхронная работа, обойтись без лямбд и сигналов:

```
QString program = "ping 127.0.0.1";

QProcess *Process = new QProcess(this);
Process->start(program);    
Process->waitForFinished();
QString output = Process->readAllStandardOutput();
qDebug()<<output;
```

PS: сдается мне что вашу программу по итогу напишет сообщество SO. 
Я думал уж с этим то справитесь, тем более что на подобный вопрос уже отвечалось

Comment: так по ссылке захватить тоже норм, чтобы не париться потом с указателями

Comment: в лямбде используются два объекта - Process (который уже указатель) и output. в любом случае что так что так под один знаменатель

Answer (score 1):

В вашем варианте вы используте асинхронное апи, поэтому ваша лямбда вызовется непонятно в какое время и нельзя сразу после старта печатать вывод, надо делать это в самой лямбде

```
QString program = "cmd", output;

command = "cd /d ";
command += QString::fromLocal8Bit(dir); //здесь хранится путь до папки, в которой должна исполняться команда
command += " & pip list";

qDebug() << command;

arg << "/C" << command;

QProcess *Process2 = new QProcess(this);

// Лямбда выражение будет выполнено после вызова Process2->start
connect(Process2, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [&] {
    output = QString::FromLocal8Bit(Process2->readAll());
    qDebug() << output;
});

Process2->start(program, arg);
```

Вариант 2 - использовать синхронное апи (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#synchronous-process-api)

```
QString program = "cmd", output;

command = "cd /d ";
command += QString::fromLocal8Bit(dir); //здесь хранится путь до папки, в которой должна исполняться команда
command += " & pip list";

qDebug() << command;

arg << "/C" << command;

QProcess *Process2 = new QProcess(this);

connect(Process2, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [&] {
    output = QString::FromLocal8Bit(Process2->readAll());
});

Process2->start(program, arg);

Process2->waitForFinished(); // Ждем завершения роцесса

qDebug() << output; // Во время waitForFinished, будет совершен асинхронный вызов лямбды, которая сохранит вывод в переменную и её можно использовать уже после завершения процесса
```

Comment: Во время waitForFinished лямбда вызовется неоднократно и в такой реализации вывод будет перезаписываться. проверьте сами вставив qDebug()<<"lambda"; в тело лямбды

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev полностью согласен, но у автора там присваивание, поэтому не менял